# $x^2+y^2 = p$ and $x^2+y^2 = q$ are not $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic when p,q are primes 3 mod 4

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry

This is a problem in Silverman's book "The arithmetic of Dynamical Systems". Concretely, problem 4.44.

If we call $X_p$ the curve with equation $x^2 + y^2 = p$, it turns out that $X_p$ is $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic to $X_1$ when $p$ is a prime 1 mod 4, but in the case of primes 3 mod 4, different primes 3 mod 4 will give different twists of $X_1$.

Any idea of how to prove it?

One approach that I tried was to prove that $X_q$ does not have solutions in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{p})$ but I failed.

Comment: Quite obviously you have to work in ${\mathbb Q}(i)$, not ${\mathbb Q}(\sqrt{p})$.

Comment: Why is quite obvious? I used $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt(p))$ because $X_p$ has rational points in it. In the case of finding rational points in $\mathbb{Q}(i)$, how does that help to say that there is no isomorphism from $\mathbb{Q}$?.

Comment: Because of the two classes of primes $p \equiv 1 \bmod 4$ and $p \equiv 3 \bmod 4$.

Comment: But $p$ and $q$ are both 3 mod 4.

Comment: p cannot be 3 mod 4

Comment: Infact p=1(mod 4) iff p=x^2+y^2 where p is prime (famous by Fermat)

Comment: No, $p$ and $q$ can be 3 mod 4. What you say is those curves do not have rational points. I agree with that. But the question is different. They are $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-isomorphic, because they are $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$-isomorphic to $X_1$ for example. The question is why a $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphism cannot be found between them.

Comment: Over $\mathbb{Q}[\sqrt{3}]$, $x^2+y^2=7$ is trivial too. (I remember I’ve done the same exercise long time ago)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Carlos Rivera for giving me the ideas. I post the solution maybe can help somebody else in the future.

Suppose $X_p$ and $X_q$ are $\mathbb{Q}$-isomorphic. This imply they are isomorphic in every extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. The trick is to prove that $X_q(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ is trivial whereas $X_p(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ is not.

$X_q(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ is trivial: Suppose $(u,v)$ is a solution in $\mathbb{Q}_q$. Using the power expansion of elements in $\mathbb{Q}_q$, there are unique $x, y \in \mathbb{Z}_q^\times$ and $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $(u,v) = (x/q^a, y/q^b)$. By symmetry, assume $a \geq b$. Putting this into the equation of $X_q$ we get $$x^2+q^{2(a-b)}y^2 = q^{2a+1}.$$

If $a > b$, $x \notin \mathbb{Z}_q^\times$, so $a = b$. Taking modulo $q$, $$x^2 \equiv -y^2 \pmod{q},$$ so $-1$ is an square modulo $q$. However, this is false when $q \equiv 3 \pmod{4}$.

$X_p(\mathbb{Q}_q)$ is not trivial. Observe that $\{x^2 : x \in \mathbb{F}_q \}$ and $\{ p - y^2: y \in \mathbb{F}_q \} $ have $(q+1)/2$ points. So, they meet in at least one point $(x_0, y_0)$. Since $q \neq p$, one of the coordinate is not $0 \pmod{q}$. Using a trick like Hensel's lemma, one can find a lift to $\mathbb{Z}_q$.

Comment: When considering a hypothetical $q$-adic solution for $x^2 + y^2 = q$, before treating the case when $u$ and $v$ are both nonzero as you did, consider the possibility that one of them might be $0$ (it's trivial to eliminate this, but it should be part of the argument).

Comment: Hasse—Minkowski tells us that two quadratic forms are equivalent if and only if they are equivalent at each local place.